# Keras CNN: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_46_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3780, 6)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I created a Conv1D model with Keras and prompted me with a ValueError during training. I don't quite understand where the model is having problems.

I tried to modify the data shape to (3780,6,1) but still prompted me conv1d_46_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3780, 6)

```py
def baseline_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(1, 5, input_shape=(6,1), activation="tanh"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(layers.core.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(2))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# df is pandas DataFrame
X = np.array(df[['rp', 'x', 'y', 'class', 'at', 'dt']], dtype=np.float64)
y = np.array(df[['ap', 'dp']], dtype=np.float64)
# X = np.expand_dims(X, -1)
# y = np.expand_dims(y, -1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=100)
mode = baseline_model()
history = mode.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

X=np.array([[-69.3078,   0.    ,   1.    ,   1.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ],
       [-69.4585,   0.    ,   2.    ,   1.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ],
       [-69.4776,   0.    ,   3.    ,   1.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ],
       ...,
       [-65.8291,  35.    ,  33.    ,   1.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ],
       [-71.0137,  35.    ,  34.    ,   1.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ],
       [-67.2308,  35.    ,  35.    ,   1.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ]])
y=np.array([[ 15.4463, -17.5046],
       [ 15.4777, -17.536 ],
       [ 15.5092, -17.5675],
       ...,
       [ 15.8361, -17.8944],
       [ 15.8809, -17.9392],
       [ 15.9259, -17.9842]])

# X,y type is numpy array
# X shape is (4725, 6) ,y shape is (4725, 2) 
# X[0] shape is (6,) , y[0] shape is (2,)
```

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_46_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3780, 6)

Comment: How exactly did you reshape your data? that should have worked

Comment: I am reshaping the data by using the np.expand_dims() function. X=np.expand_dims(X,2)

Comment: That should have worked, are you sure the error is the same? Please include it and the actual fitting code.

Comment: I updated my code.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first Conv layer is expecting a data Dim that looks like (Batch_size, dim1, dim2)
Here you have a X shape of (3780, 6), so 3780 arrays of dim 6, but you need to have 3780 arrays of dim (6, 1).

In order to do that, you can simply expand the dim of your X, by doing that :

```
X = np.expand_dims(X, -1)
```

This will add the extra dimension that you need.

Comment: I used this operation, X.shape is (4725, 6, 1) ,but triggered a new exception.ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3780, 2, 1)

Comment: Y need to have a shape of (batch_size, nb_class), so for that error you need to get ride of the last dim of your y, do a simple :
y = np.squeeze(y)

Comment: I saw you expand_dims the label array too, you don't need to do that because it have to be a 2D array and not a 3D

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, my problem has been solved, which has taught me a lot.